# Como pegar os últimos valores inseridos de duas tabelas, e ordena-los pelo último acesso?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sql-select

Preciso criar um `select` que pegue os `id's` de duas tabelas, una-os e me mostre o último registro dos dois juntos. Tentei assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.cod_mobilibus, p.nome, q.dt_acesso
FROM pr_pontos p
RIGHT JOIN pr_qr_pontos q ON p.cod_mobilibus = q.cod_mobilibus
ORDER BY q.dt_acesso DESC
```

Meu maior problema é que os resultados que eu receber não podem ser iguais.

Estrutura tabela 1

```
 id_acesso / cod_mobilibus / dt_acesso
```

Estrutura tabela 2

```
 id_ponto / cod_mobilibus / nome / endereco / cidade / bairro / codigo
```

Comment: pode postar a estrutura das duas tabelas?

Comment: Opa, atualizei o post.

Comment: como assim os resultados não podem ser iguais?

Comment: Vou explicar mais detalhado. Tenho vários qrcodes onde a pessoa acessa e leva ela pra um site. Essa entrada registra o valor na base de dados na tabela 1. Na tabela 2 estão as definições dos "pontos" da tabela 1. Então eu preciso do último registro de cada ponto, mas não podem ser repetidos os cod_mobilibus, pois dois usuários podem acessar esse qrcode, mas quero apenas o acesso mais recente do mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente dessa forma amigo:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    exemplo2 e2 INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  exemplo1.id_acesso, exemplo1.cod_mobilibus,
                    MAX(exemplo1.dt_acesso) dt_acesso
            FROM exemplo1
            GROUP BY exemplo1.cod_mobilibus
        ) e1 ON (e1.cod_mobilibus = e2.cod_mobilibus)
```

**Explicação**

No `INNER JOIN` faça um `SELECT` para trazer os dados que deseja unir com a sua outra tabela, nesse caso, você queria apenas uma `tupla` que tivesse a data mais nova. Então um `SELECT` usando a função `MAX()` para passar e pegar a última `dt_acesso` e um `GROUP BY` por `cod_mobilibus` para que obtenha apenas uma informação de cada. Feito isso basta terminar o `INNER JOIN`, comparando as tabelas pelo `cod_mobilibus`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Foi bem útil para mim.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que com uma subquery você consiga garantir que está pegando o ultimo resultado de cada registro.

select * from tabela1 as t1
inner join tabela2 as t2 on t1.cod_mobilibus  = t2.cod_mobilibus

where 
t1.dt_acesso  = (select tmp.dt_acesso from tabela1 as tmp  where tmp.cod_mobilibus  = t1.cod_mobilibus order by desc limit 1)

order by t1.dt_acesso

Comment: Tentei utilizar esse código, mas mesmo que eu altere algumas coisas, só me retorna `select * from pr_qr_pontos as t1 inner join pr_pontos as t2 on t1.cod_mobilibus = t2.cod_mobilibus

where t1.dt_acesso = (select dt_acesso from pr_qr_pontos order by desc limit 1)

order by t1.dt_acesso`
Ou então quando eu adiciono o dt_acesso depois de order by retorna isso `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: Fiz uma alteração. Tente novamente!

Comment: Não consegui o que queria, vou tentar outra pergunta. Mas obrigado pela ajuda!